# Why does my result keep showing up as undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I did this code for one of my classes (keep in mind it's beginner classes and we just started learning about else if). It supposed to write down someone's name, SSN, wages, time, and the final pay with the taxes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
<!-- Author: Sidney Stephens
Assignment ? - Part ?: Title: ?
Date: [[date:%d/%m%Y %H:%M"%S]]
Description: ???
-->

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" <!-- Character Setter -->
    <title>CMIS102 &raquo; Sidney Stephens &raquo; Assignment ? Part ? </title>
    <script>
    document.write("<h1>Payroll Calculator</h1>")
    window.alert("This is the Dynasty Casino Payroll Program.");
    sName = window.prompt("Who's payroll?","");
    document.write("<p>Name: </p>" + sName);
    sSSN = window.prompt("What is their SSN?","");
    document.write("<p>SSN: </p>" + sSSN);;
    sEntry = window.prompt("Hourly Rate?","0");
    var fRate = parseFloat(sEntry);
    document.write("<p>Rate: </p>" + fRate);
    sEntry = window.prompt("How many hours worked?","0");
    var fTime = parseFloat(sEntry);
    document.write("<p>Time: </p>" + fTime);
    if (fTime > 40)
    {
        var sDiff = fTime - 40;
        var fDiff = parseFloat(sDiff);
        document.write("<p>Overtime Worked: </p>" + fDiff);
        var sRaw = (fRate * 40) + ((fRate * 1.5) * fDiff);
        var fRaw = parseFloat(sRaw);
        document.write("<p>Pay Without Taxes: </p>" + fRaw);
        if (fRaw <= 1000)
        {
            var sFinal = fRaw * 0.85;
            var fFinal = parseFloat(sFinal);
            window.alert("You will recieve $" + fFinal);
            document.write("<p>Final Pay: </p>" + fFinal);
        }

        else if (fRaw > 1000)
        {
            var sExtra = fRaw - 1000;
            var fExtra = parseFloat(sExtra);
            var sfinal = (fExtra * 0.75) + (1000 * 0.85);
            window.alert(sFinal);
            var fFinal = parseFloat(sFinal);
            window.alert("You will recieve $" + sFinal);
            document.write("<p>Final Pay: </p>" + sFinal);
        }
    }

    else if (fTime <= 40)
    {
        var sRaw = 40 * fRate;
        var fRaw = parseFloat(sRaw);
        document.write("<p>Pay Without Taxes: </p>" + fRaw);
        if (fRaw <= 1000)
        {
            var sFinal = fRaw * 0.85;
            var fFinal = parseFloat(sFinal);
            window.alert("You will recieve $" + fFinal);
            document.write("<p>Final Pay: </p>" + fFinal);
        }

        else if (fRaw > 1000)
        {
            var sExtra = fRaw - 1000;
            var fExtra = parseFloat(sExtra);
            var sfinal = ((fExtra * 0.75)) + ((1000 * 0.85));
            window.alert(sFinal);
            var fFinal = parseFloat(sFinal);
            window.alert("You will recieve $" + fFinal);
            document.write("<p>Final Pay: </p>" + fFinal);
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <p>This is the template</p>
</body>
```

It works fine for me except when sRaw is over 1000 then for some reason it keeps saying NaN or undefined. We haven't really gone in depth with the attractiveness of it. We pretty much gotten as far as getting algorithms to work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `window.propmt` is ugly UI-wise. `document.write` is ugly in all respects.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What's the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: That unclosed meta charset tag could be problematic... and it's certainly invalid.

Comment: Do check your code for unclosed tags. At first glance they're not the cause of the error but these could be symptoms of the problem.

Comment: Not te best and modern code ever, but in what context do you get the error? In what if do you face it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a typo in your code

```
else if (fRaw > 1000)
        {
            var sExtra = fRaw - 1000;
            var fExtra = parseFloat(sExtra);
            var sfinal = (fExtra * 0.75) + (1000 * 0.85);//here, change sfinal  to sFinal
            window.alert(sFinal);
            var fFinal = parseFloat(sFinal);
            window.alert("You will recieve $" + sFinal);
            document.write("<p>Final Pay: </p>" + sFinal);
        }
```

It took a lot of time to find this simple little typo!! The moral you should learn "Typo; never let them happen"